# Ways of calling non static method from main in Java

Tags: java, methods, static, program-entry-point

We all know that we cannot call a non-static method from Java's static main method directly. I've written 2 ways to call non-static method from main (shown below).

**What I wanted to ask is:** Is there any significance difference between using `code 1` and `code 2` to overcome the limitation?

**Code 1**

```
public class Demo 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {           
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        demo.printText();
    }

    public void printText()
    {
        System.out.println("Method successfully called.");
    }   
}
```

**Code 2**

```
public class Demo 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {           
        new Demo().printText();    
    }

    public void printText()
    {
        System.out.println("Method successfully called.");
    }   
}
```

**NOTE:** In school, our professor told us "In Java, staticmethods of a class can be invoked through the name of the class in which they are defined, without having to instantiate an object of the class first."

But in `code 2` no object was instantiated, yet I was able to call the non static-method?

Comment: `new Demo()` instantiates the object, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221662/why-take-object-name-new-object/24221712#24221712

Comment: Btw, why the down vote?

Comment: Because you made the assumption that you're "calling the method without instantiating the object", even though that's exactly you're doing. You just never stored the reference, but it's STILL an instantiated instance of the class. Thus, people deemed that this is a low quality question, as the question seems to lack `basic` knowledge about Java and references and object instantiation which are part of the tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: Both are valid, but often enough, if you find yourself creating objects to call a single method, your method should be static

Comment: Sounds like `printText()` might need to be a `static` method.  If it makes sense to call a method without instantiating an object, it probably ought to be a static method...

Comment: Well, if the function does not rely on instance-specific states, anyways (I am thinking of the `Random` class and its `nextInt()` function)

Comment: @Zhuinden It may be a very basic question to many of you, but I am sure this question will benefit many new Java learners which having hard time to understand the technical documentation.

Comment: Valid point. Now you know the answer.

Comment: @Zhuinden yes. And to all people, pls kindly stop down voting. I am leaving this question in SO, so that it can possibly benefit other  new Java learners in future.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main things to be considered while using the first one over the second..

1. you will still have a reference to the `Demo` object, so you can call `demo.someOtheMethod()`.
2. Your demo object will not be ready for *Garbage collection* as soon as `printext()` returns. i.e, it will not be ready until you actually exit `main()`. In the second case, it will be ready as soon as `printext()` returns..

Comment: Care to explain why #2 is an advantage?

Comment: @TheLostMind Care to elaborate more on garbage collection between first and second case? Is it bad practice to use `code 2` ?

Comment: @IdanArye - Sorry.. The second one is *not* an advantage. changed the answer to reflect the same.

Comment: @user3437460 - Not exactly. If you don't want the reference to persist, then the second option is actually good. for example, new Thread(new Runnable()...// code to override run()); This ensures that the thread runs only once and prepares Thread and Runnable objects for GC earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that you can reuse the value in the object demo later. However, you should not create an instance just to call such a method. The correct way to do this is to make the method static.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any difference of executing code or the creating the object.

But in the second method, you don't have a reference to the object you created.(in first method, `demo` is the reference for the `Demo`object) So you can't do any other thing with this object further, as there is no way of referencing it.

as example:
Suppose you had another method inside class Demo called `foo1()`

in first example you can run both method using a single object.

```
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    demo.printText();
    demo.foo1();
```

but in the second method, You have to do it with 2 objects seperately.

```
new Demo().printText();
new Demo().foo1();
```

Comment: Please note that the second version creates two objects, aka it instantiates two objects which isn't necessarily the right solution. I saw a code where the person was doing `canvas.drawText("whatever", 20, 20, new Paint());` on every `onDraw()` function call, which is extremely cringe-worthy `memory leak` (or at least it forces the GC to be constantly doing its job). Aka a source of `bad performance` and `bad memory management`.

Answer (score 0):

In Code1, you are creating an object using the class name as a reference variable, and calling that function and this would work very finely.
in code2, you are creating an anonymous object, which is basically used whenever we want to use the object only once in the lifecycle of the class.

In both code, the program will work finely.